# Where does the Palace of the Prophets get its money?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

In *The Stone of Tears* (Book 2 in “The Sword of Truth”) the Palace of the Prophets gives its wizards a virtually unlimited supply of gold coins and also gives it out handsomely to

> anyone who births a child that has magic.

We also see in later books that Verna is balancing the budget and paying off expenses for carpentry, burial services, etc.

Where does the Palace get all this money? Do they just magic it up? Or do they have some source of traditional income?

Comment: I've shared this post to a closed FB fan club of the series. Will post a consensus answer shortly

Comment: Playing the stock market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is not written directly in the books and no other canon information is available at the moment, we will have to make an intelligent guess.

It looks like the Sisters and Wizards create some gold, some is produced by businesses owned by The Palace. Also, some gold might have been accumulated over the thousands of years since the Palace was built. After all, the Wizards of old were the power and could have all the gold they wanted.

However, Zedd warned against such use of magic in SoT, when he had to convert copper pieces to gold, as it may violate the Wizard's Second Rule:

> “The Second Rule is that the greatest harm can result from the best intentions. It sounds a paradox, but kindness and good intentions can be an insidious path to destruction. Sometimes doing what seems right is wrong, and can cause harm. The only counter to it is knowledge, wisdom, forethought, and understanding the First Rule. Even then, that is not always enough.”

And we may come to a conclusion that it did. Wizards having unlimited supply of gold and loose moral restraints on their behavior became arrogant, and easily seduced by the Keeper's minions.

Comment: "Some is produced by businesses owned by The Palace". Which businesses are those?

Comment: @Thunderforge as I wrote in the answer, it is based on assumptions, not any canon source, because there is none available.

It is a possibility that The Palace could own or participate in some profitable business, because they are technically a source of money that could be borrowed. The Palace owns and runs a lot of properties, such as the stables, kitchens, etc. I do not see a reason why could it not own a business in town, or lend to one for interest.

Comment: I always thought that the palace magicked up all the gold they needed. Zedd explains that the Sisters are not at all like wizards and we know that Warren has no idea about the Wizard's Rules despite all his training. It made me think that the Sisters would not think twice about creating gold because they were ignorant of the damage it would cause.